# How to Replace the value using the old value in particular key in LinkedHashMap in java

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, key-value-store

I have an old value stored in it as map{key,value}.
I want to update the existing value by performing calculations on it like increasing the value by 10 when its an integer; 
map{key,value+10}

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Reading the documentation would be a good start.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: This sounds like a very simple question unless you want to do it without changing the iteration order of the `LinkedHashMap`. Is that what you are asking? If so please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use `computeIfPresent` (example assuming a `Map<String, Integer>`):

```
map.computeIfPresent("key", (String key, Integer value) -> value + 10);
```

This method allows you to compute the new value mapped to the given key. In the above example, the existing value will be replaced with `oldValue + 10`.

`Map.computeIfPresent`:

> If the value for the specified key is present and non-null, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value.

If you need to upsert, then the correct method to use is `merge`, which inserts if the key is not already associated with a value in the map:

```
map.merge("key", 1, (Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) -> oldValue + newValue);
```

In that example, `1` is the new value to be added if the `"key"` doesn't exist in `map`. If `"key"` is not new in the map, then the function in the third argument is called to compute the updated value (in this example, it will just increment whatever was there by the new value).

Comment: Is there a way to make this into a `insert` or `update if present`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes. Edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick

```
Map<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
linkedHashMap.put(/*your_desired_key*/, linkedHashMap.get(/*your_desired_key*/) + 10) ;
```

Comment: i think you want to get the value, add 10, then put it with the same key. eg. map.put(key, map.get(key)+10);

Comment: @Pankaj: As there was no code available, I added that for readability and to avoid any assumptions